# What's the fastest way to send the same http request repeatedly?

Tags: http, curl, httpclient

I want to send the same http request repeatedly unless I get the right response, and the server is slow, sending the request is quick, receiving the response is quick also, but waiting for server to handle the request is slow. So if I send the request, and then waiting the failure should not be acceptable.

I think of the following workflow:
1)Sending the request
2)After sending the data, start a new request to send the same request

repeat 1-2, and the response should be handled asynchronously, and when detecting the right response, it stop sending request.

How to achieve this workflow or any other workflow can solve my problem. Any language and tool which will be fast would be considerable, like C/C++.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how is your server going to service a request any *faster* when it is being request-bombed by your client?

Comment: @WhozCraig You're so fast, It's not my server, and a lot of people are waiting for big gift in 0' clock, and I am one of them.

Comment: What @WhozCraig is trying to say, is that the more requests you send, the slower the server will be, especially for everyone else. It's simply a denial-of-service attack you are planning on.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you, but I will control the speed, and I hope this question will not offend anyone, and also this is a true program question.

Comment: If site you're doing this to has even the remotest half-baked engineering on its back-side, it will immediately reject any requests sent during any official "contest time" if there is already a pending request from the same source net-address. Woe to those behind a proxy, but such is life. Launching a DoS during contests is likely grounds for forfeiture any, and if it isn't, the company is run by idiots. Best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig It's not the problem, and I just want my technical problem to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

This will cause the server to simply respond slower and slower; your first request will be the first to receive any response, all the others will be wasted CPU time and bandwidth - if you did that to my servers you'd get your IP banned automatically.

What you need to consider is

- why do you need the response *this* fast?
- can you cache the response so that re-requesting it is no longer needed
- perhaps having a caching proxy between your client(s) and the server will cover your needs? (also, prefetching)

Comment: The time is limit, and when the response is wrong, and I will lose the chance to finish my request. So, in the limit time, I must send as many requests as possible to expect one of them to succeed. Your solution should not be acceptable.

Comment: For what operation is there a time limit? For *your* program's execution? For the remote server to respond?

Comment: I want to have a gift, and the server will give it in 0' clock, the time is very short.

Comment: Is it 0000 your time or the server's time?